# Send intent to create an alarm in default app

Tags: ios, alarm

In android we can do an Intent to add an alarm to the default alarm app installed on the device [example](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/AlarmClock).

I wonder if it's possible to achieve something similar on iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding to Alarm App, [Here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/33824?answerId=108518022#108518022) you have answer from Apple support and it's related with [iOS sandbox](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/33824?answerId=109961022#109961022).

> As far as I know the rationale for this has never been publicly documented.  However, the iOS sandbox does not, in general, allow app A to make changes that affect app B or the system as a whole.

In Apple [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/eventkit/setting_an_alarm) you can find description how to set up calendar alarms.

Comment: That is an alarm attached to an event. This is different to setting an alarm in the clock app, which is what I believe the op is asking about. There is no api for the clock app to add alarms.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks, that's was what I was asking for, there is no possibility to add alarms to the clock app from an other app?